# Replace last two characters in column

Tags: sql

I have a column with dates in the format 201201, 201202, 201203 etc.

This is a financial database so there is a period 13; however periods 12 & 13 are combined for reporting purposes.

When the last two characters are 13, how do I replace them with 12?

I started off with

```
SELECT REPLACE(PERIOD, '13', '12')
FROM @b_s_summary
```

but, of course this messes with the year when it's 2013.

All advice gratefully received.

Comment: What database? Available functions may vary. Add a tag or edit your question.

Comment: IMO, the question 'Replace last two characters in column' is wrong, since the characters in this case are always the third and the fourth.

Comment: @FabianBigler: Not 3rd and 4th--5th and 6th. "201201" means the first accounting period in 2012. The 13th accounting period in 2012 would be "201213". One of my earliest professional programming jobs was writing software to determine shareholder value for a multi-national Fortune 100 company. The number of accounting periods varied from 7 to 54 per year. (Before you ask, no, I can't explain that.)

Comment: @Mike: Ok, thanks! I got confused because he was talking about Period '13' so I thought he meant the business years. After rereading it was obvious. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Substring in this case:

```
SELECT REPLACE(PERIOD, SUBSTRING(PERIOD, len(PERIOD) - 1, 2), '12')
FROM @b_s_summary WHERE PERIOD LIKE '%13'
```

Does that fit you, or do you need a more dynamic approach for past or upcoming years?

Comment: Many thanks to all, all good and valuable answers but I can only mark one as "the" answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @Periods as Table ( Period VarChar(6) )
insert into @Periods ( Period ) values
  ( '201212' ), ( '201213' ), ( '201312' ), ( '201313' ) 

select Period, case
  when Right( Period, 2 ) = '13' then Substring( Period, 1, 4 ) + '12'
  else Period end as [AdjustedPeriod]
  from @Period
```

Answer (score 1):

Likewise, RIGHT() could be used.

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(PERIOD,2),'13','12')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select (case when right(period, 2) = '13' then left(period, 4) + '12' else period end)
```

Fairly standard SQL, but some databases might need `substr()` or `substring()` instead of `right()` and `left()`.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT LEFT(PERIOD, Len(PERIOD) - 2)
FROM   @b_s_summary
```

Comment: Looks like that will just fetch the year.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?