# How to replace the last character of a substring with another character contingent on another field string value

Tags: mysql, replace

I'm trying to replace the 12th character of a value in a field `retro_game_id` with another character.  The value is a string and the last character is '0'.  I need to replace the '0' with '2' when the last character of another string value of another field in the same table `id` is '2'. An example of the value of the first field is 'BAL200809230'. An example of a string in the other field is '2008/09/23/tbamlb-balmlb-2'

So using the above as an example, I need to change 'BAL200809230' to 'BAL200809232' of the `retro_game_id` field only when the corresponding value of the `id` field has a '2' at the end as in '2008/09/23/tbamlb-balmlb-2'

I tried the following code using the following links to guide me but to no avail: [Replace last two characters in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696874/replace-last-two-characters-in-column)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413216/sql-replace-last-2-chars-if-last-2-chars-matches)

[MySQL string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)

```
SELECT `retro_game_id` FROM atbats_pitches_python_new
SET `retro_game_id`= REPLACE(RIGHT(`retro_game_id`,1),'0','2')
WHERE RIGHT(`id`, 1) ='2
```

Can someone please assist with the correct code to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are confusing select and update.  If you want to alter the actual data in the `atbats_pitches_python_new` then you want to be doing an update.  Do a conditional update of the `retro_game_id` field when its corresponding `id` field ends in `2`:

```
UPDATE atbats_pitches_python_new
SET retro_game_id = CONCAT(LEFT(retro_game_id, CHAR_LENGTH(retro_game_id) - 1), '2')
WHERE
    RIGHT(id, 1) = '2';
```

The trick here is to take a substring of `retro_game_id` including all characters except for the last one.  Then, concatenate this substring with `2`.

Comment: Thank you Tim, worked great!  I see it now--Take the first 11 characters as a substring and attach it to the new last (12th) character '2'.

Comment: I'd use `LEFT(col, length)` instead of `SUBSTRING(col, 1, length)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Good idea, but I think you meant to say `LEFT(col, length - 1)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes and No :-) I left it to you to replace it with the correct expression